# Polynomial Division of a "Special" Polynomial

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, polynomials, binomial-coefficients

Let $$f(m)=(2n+1)((2n+1)^2-1^2)((2n+1)^2-3^2)\ldots((2n+1)^2-(2m-3)^2)/(2m-1)!$$
for some Positive integers $n,m$   
we have to find the coefficients of $t^{1-k}$ quotient  on polynomial Division of 
$$nf(n+1)t^{n-1}+(n-1)f(n)t^{n-2}+(n-2)f(n-1)t^{n-3}+(n-3)f(n-2)t^{n-4}+\ldots$$
by the polynomial 
$$f(n+1)t^{n}+f(n)t^{n-1}+f(n-1)t^{n-2}+f(n-2)t^{n-3}+f(n-3)t^{n-4}+\ldots$$
with respect to $t$
I am curious about this since when I attempted to do this I saw a Pattern for

```
   k=2 coefficient=n
   k=3 coefficient=(2n+1)/4
   k=4 coefficient=3(2n+1)/16
   k=5 coefficient=5(2n+1)/32
   k=6 coefficient=35(2n+1)/256
   k=7 coefficient=63(2n+1)/512
   k=8 coefficient=231(2n+1)/2048
   k=9 coefficient=429(2n+1)/4096
   k=10 coefficient=6435(2n+1)/65536
```

I primarily noticed the pattern of power of two's in the denominator and attempted to fix them to form a more uniform format, The pattern of numerators was seen by me to follow a general form, which made me conjecture that this coefficient for some $k=p$ was $\binom{2p-5}{p-2}(2n+1)/2^{2p-4}$ except for p=2 where the binomial is invalid and we have it as $n$.
[OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C3%2C10%2C35&sort=&language=english&go=Search) appears to confirm the sequence's conjectured general term.
 
I want to ask the correctness (if correct then proof) of this conjecture or how do we get the required coefficient?

Comment: Any insight or hint to approach would be highly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C3%2C5%2C35%2C63&language=english&go=Search) ?

Comment: I missed on the $2^{2p}$ in the denominator, sorry for that.

Comment: Thank-you for your suggestion. I attempted it recently, and found the pattern to be analogous to mine (probably identical) [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C3%2C10%2C35&sort=&language=english&go=Search)